# Selenium Webdriver | Unable to locate element error

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java, browser-automation

I am trying to run the below code but getting error. Can you please point out the issue?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;


public class SelTe2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://wpadhinj.techmahindra.com/wpad.dat");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost");

    // Open Bing Search Engine
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    wd.get("http://www.bing.com/?cc=in");

    // Search for Kotak and navigate to Net Banking Secure Login 
    WebElement we1 = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@title, 'search')]"));
    we1.sendKeys("kotak");
    we1.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a/strong[text()='Kotak']")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[text()='Net Banking']")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@title='NetBanking Secure Login']")).click();

    // Switch to child window
    for (String handles : wd.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!wd.getTitle().contains(wd.getWindowHandle())){
            wd.switchTo().window(handles);
        }
    }

    // Wait for 15 sec. while page loads
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Enter Username and Password
    wd.findElement(By.name("Username")).sendKeys("selenium");
    wd.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("selenium");

    }    
}
```

Error Description: -

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"Username"}
Command duration or timeout: 15.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_43'
Session ID: 73e4a32c-9447-4242-a13b-7bc5a9f21406
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=20.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:380)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:292)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at SelTe2.main(SelTe2.java:44)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"Username"}
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_43'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/SS0041~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous5139644307112851862webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8281)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/SS0041~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous5139644307112851862webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:382)`

Comment: Error is thrown on the last section where I enter Username.

Comment: It may help for you to specify the error message.

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with the name "Username"?  Is the element in an iframe?

Comment: @SamWoods This is what inspect element says -

`<td class="trLogin" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" align="left" valign="top"><input class="loginTextbox" type="text" maxlength="50/" onfocus="setFlag(this);" onkeypress="return checkExclusive('userid')" name="Username"></input></td>`

Comment: Further up the tree, is that td inside of an iframe?

Comment: @user246 Have added the error description in the question please help.

Comment: @SamWoods Sorry not very conversant with Web design! This is the Xpath `/html/body/form/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input` and it appears under `<frameset> \ <frame>`. Does this help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that the element is within a <frameset> \ <frame>.  To work with any element within a frame, you need to first switch the context of the driver from the main page to that frame:

`driver.switchTo().frame("foo");`

In this example "foo" would be the name of the iframe.  You can also do it by index if the frame has no name value.

If you need to switch back to the main page, outside of the frame you would use:
`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

There is a little more detail in the documentation: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp.
Look for switchTo().frame

Answer (score 0):

Try using something as follows :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("Username")));
driver.findElement(By.name("Username")).sendKeys("selenium");
```