# Error - An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#

[image]I am trying to click on a tab - a rather simple task.But, I get the error message above. I have added a thread.sleep command - in case it is due to synchronization issues. Your help is highly appreciated:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CV_Lib_Do_Not_Use
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            //Go to CV Library Website
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/");

            //Wait for web element to become visible
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);


            //Click on Search Jobs tab
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='header-nav-new']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();

        }
    }
}
```

I have checked previous errors from:

[Selenium webdriver - Unable to locate element,xpath,error](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7313/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-locate-element-xpath-error)

[Selenium Webdriver | Unable to locate element error](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-locate-element-error)

The solutions were not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are no elements matching the XPath expression.*

There is actually a much simpler way to locate the "Search Jobs" link - by "id":

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("header-link-searchjobs")).click();
```

Note that, instead of `Sleep()` call, you should use an [Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/771848):

```
var wait = WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id("header-link-searchjobs"))).click();
```

Comment: That worked!! How did you get "header-link-searchjobs", please ?

I can't seem to get it by using firepath / firebug..

Many Thanks

Comment: @OA345 just inspected the element with chrome developer tools. Glad to see it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I have taken a screen shot of the Chrome Developer. But I could not locate the tag that you suggested earlier. I have attached a screen shot.

Please, can you help. Thank you.

Comment: @OA345 interesting, your desired element looks in the page source this way `<a href="/search-jobs" id="header-link-searchjobs">Search Jobs</a>`. Does it look the same to you?

Comment: Where exactly in the page / tab are you looking at please ?

Can you see the screen shot I attached ?

Thank you

Comment: @OA345 I am looking at the https://www.cv-library.co.uk/ page, second "Search Jobs" tab on the top of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61261/discussion-between-oa345-and-alecxe).